# Marklogic Server Side Javascript: XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES while using explicit commit

Tags: javascript, marklogic, sjs

I've been having problems with conflicting updates in Marklogic. I'm aware of the cause, but I don't know how to fix it. 
I have 1 main (*.sjs) file which calls two different (*.sjs) files which both update a set of documents. In the main file I use: `declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true});` and then in the separate files I use the command `xdmp.commit();` after updating the documents. However, I'm still getting: `XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES`.

Part of the code: Main.sjs:

```
function main(){
  declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true});
  function.to.file.1();
  function.to.file.2();
}
```

file1.sjs:

```
//make some docs and insert them into ML
function file1Function(){
    for (let d of someCollectionOfData) {
      xdmp.documentInsert('/a/uri/filexx.json', d, {collections: aCollectionName1});
    };
    xdmp.commit();
}
```

file2.sjs:

```
//adjust docs made in file1 and put them back into ML
funtion file2Function(){
  for (let d of xdmp.directory('/location/of/aCollectionName1/','infinity')) {
    let dObj = d.toObject();
    dObj.addSomething = 'something';
    xdmp.documentInsert(fn.documentUri(d), dObj, {collections: aCollectionName1});
  }
  xdmp.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must mean your file1 is located inside '/location/of/aCollectionName1/'. Keep in mind that MarkLogic doesn't commit immediately when you invoke xdmp.commit(). Actual persisting is always postponed until after all code has executed. It therefor doesn't make much sense to invoke xdmp.commit() more than once in one request. You won't be able to read your updates after xdmp.commit().

HTH!

Comment: So, how can I, in one procedure, edit a document multiple times? Keep in mind that these edits can depend on each other and are performed dynamically. That's why I want to do them in one procedure.

Comment: You'll need to update an in-memory copy of the contents multiple times until you are done, and only then save the result. This library could help you with that: https://github.com/ryanjdew/XQuery-XML-Memory-Operations

Comment: So is there a difference between just using declareUpdate() at the beginning of the code or using declareUpdate({explicitCommit: true}) in combination with xdmp.commit()? If persistence only takes place after code execution I would say not. So what's the point then in having two different ways of achieving the same thing?

Comment: With explicit commit you can just skip commit to get updates rolled back, without needing to throw an exception. That is a little quicker. That said, so far I haven't used explicit commit myself yet.